# TinyMCE криво отображает HTML

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Закидываю контент из базы, контент типа **HTML**. Он вначале отображает нормально, но стоит что-нибудь изменить - как все, все сбивается, контент уже теряет вид, где-то отступы больше, где-то меньше.
Подскажите как исправить, или подскажите редактор чётче **TinyMCE** ;)

Comment: TinyMCE — это криво всегда и везде. Переходите на CKEditor, он и работает получше, и документация пополнее.

Comment: @Zelta, да он кривой. Но в MODX Revolution его реально классным сделали. Даже CKEditor курит в сторонке

Comment: @Zelta, http://modx.com/download/ - качаем Traditional версию.
мануал - http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/

нормального демо админки не нашел. простая в установке. ничего замутного. Это CMF. Имея верстку корпоративного сайта и набитую руку, можно собрать полноценный сайт за пол дня

Comment: Стоп, вы не поняли. Мне не нужен шаблонизатор, мне нужен визуальный текстовый редактор (WYSIWYG)

Comment: Ну дык я про WYSIWYG и говорю. http://ckeditor.com/ — вот, наслаждайся)

Comment: Да, и встроенные загрузчики, и кастомизация. Ну и open-source.

Comment: @Lektor, Zelta попросил ссылку на доку MODX, вот я и скинул